The descriptor for message type .google.protobuf.Timestamp cannot be found and a placeholder is created for it
I'm getting the above warning while executing tests. It seems that it doesn't affect anything and the tests are executed successfully. Any Idea why I'm seeing this warning?

The problem was that the descriptors from transitive dependencies were not included in the final descriptor file.
In gradle protobuf task I've added task.descriptorSetOptions.includeImports = true.
That fixed the problem.

most probably you are just missing an import of some library. can you paste your code here?
